# React native pdf - cannot view pdf in android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, react-native-pdf

I am using react-native Expo, and using `react-native-pdf`for viewing the pdf.

However, in android device, users cannot view the pdf, but they can view the pdf in IOS device.

The url I am using:
http://content-dev.s3-website.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/CCCC.pdf

I am not sure if it's because the url is not encrypted.

Does anyone know the reason?

```
  function showPdf() {
    const Pdf = require('react-native-pdf').default;
    return (
      <Pdf
        scale={1}
        trustAllCerts={false}
        cache={true}
        source={{
          uri: data.url,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

That's what Android device shows
[image]

**Update**
I've tried to replace the url to `https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'.
It shows successfully, so I think it's because my application doesn't allow HTTP connection.